# bit holder v.s. hex bit socket v.s. nut driver

Tags: drill

I have a novice question. What are the differences among bit holder v.s. hex bit socket v.s. nut driver? They all look similar. Can I use them interchangeably?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use them interchangeably, as long as they're the same size.

A "bit-holder" will often be magnetized to hold the bit in (and incidentally holding the screw as well) while the other two can be, but it's not as common.

A "hex bit socket" or "nut driver" is probably more durable than a "bit holder" if it matters to you, for example if you're using a high torque impact driver.